# Duplicate part of a line to another part

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I would like to copy the first part (**IxoscaEVm****t1**_, without the **'.p[number]'**) of the line starting with ">" and paste a before the last ":" of the same line.

Input:

```
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal :13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal :1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal :315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

expected output:

```
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

Comment: What is the first "part"? Will it be the string between the fasta header (`>`) and the first whitespace? Can you have spaces in the first "part"?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Don't worry, I'll fix the formatting: we can't use markdown (bold etc.) in code blocks, only in quote blocks, but since `>` denotes a quote, you can't easily have `>` in that. It's a pain, I know. Just stick to code and forget the bold, even though they help. So, can we be sure there will be no whitespace before the `.p1`? And will it _always_ be a `.p1`, never `.p2` or nothing at all?

Comment: By the way, what kind of identifiers are these? I've never seen them before. Oh, and you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Thanks! will look at it. These are protein coordinates. I am trying to build a custom Transdecoder protein file from selected transcripts for Trinotate annotation.

Comment: Yes, I can see they're peptides, I was just wondering about the identifiers. What identifier is this `IxoscaEVm2293881t1`? I haven't seen that style before. What database does it refer to? Sorry. I'm just curious, I thought I knew most of the standard ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'split($1,a,/[>.]/) > 1{ $NF=a[2] $NF } 1' file
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```bash
$ sed 's/^>\(\([^.]*\).*\):/>\1\2:/' file
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

The `sed` substitution replaces everything from the start of any line beginning with the standard Fasta header marker `>`, up to and including the last `:` on that line.  While doing so, it captures the part between the `>` up to (but not including) the first dot (this is the identifier), and also the whole start of the line, but not the final `:` character. The replacement part of the substitution is the line up to where the identifier should be inserted, followed by the identifier and a `:`.

A similar thing with an in-line Perl subsitution:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's/^>((.*?)\..*):/>$1$2:/' file
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

With Perl again, using named capture groups:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's/^>(?<partial_line>(?<id>.*?)\..*):/>$+{partial_line}$+{id}:/' file
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -pe 'if(/^\s*>(\S+?)\.p1/){$name=$1; s/(.*):/$1$name:/}' file.pep 
>IxoscaEVm2293881t1.p1 type:complete len:255 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2293881t1:13-219(+)
MFLRQLGAPRFYYARLFLRFIAVTIGPFLKSFPEKMLFLTYFPFYFWQRFSNINKRRKLLPATFLTLG
>IxoscaEVm2798449t1.p1 type:partial5 len:345 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm2798449t1:1-183(+)
CEEREKLQFPTLVELFSTMKLLSCFPGLTLNIMGANIKRVRVSKLLNKYFAVEGRTWRVC
>IxoscaEVm3186316t1.p1 type:partial5 len:317 gc:Universal IxoscaEVm3186316t1:315-151(+)
NRIARLIGKNAEAGSVNYFFVSGSLLFGKPEQCALNLFLFLHSYYTLPFFIWCI
```

**Assumptions**

- There are no whitespace characters before the first `.p1`.
- All lines that begin with a `>` also have `.p1`.

The script is relatively straightforward: if this line starts with 0 or more whitespace characters and then a `>` (`if(/^\s*>(\S+?)\.p1/)`), so if it is a header line, then store the string before the first `.p1` in the variable `$name` (`$name=$1`, this works because we captured the `(\S+?)` using parentheses in the previous step). We then replace everything until the last `:` on the line with whatever was matched, then the name and then a `:` (`s/(.*):/$1$name:/`).

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(\s*>)(IxoscaEVm.*t1)(.*)(:.*)/,"\\1\\2\\3\\2\\4", "g")}' file
```

Or

```
$ awk '/^>IxoscaEVm.*t1/{$NF = $1 $NF; gsub(/^>|\.p[0-9]{1,}/, "", $NF)}1' ffile
```